# grub-update in GRUB Legacy (0.97)

Tags: windows, dual-boot, grub-legacy

I have reinstalled grub, because I have done an install of Windows 7. The problem is that grub doesn't see Windows. I know, that in grub2 I can run grub-update and it will find all my systems. But I don't know how to do this grub legacy. I'm using Fedora 15.

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll have to declare the Windows partition manually in `/boot/grub/menu.lst`. An entry for Windows typically looks like this:

```
title Windows
root (hd0,0)
makeactive
chainloader +1
```

`hd0` means that Windows is on the boot drive, and `hd1` would mean that it's on the first drive encountered by the BIOS that isn't the boot drive. Partition numbering in Grub 1 starts at 0, so that `(hd0,0)` is what Linux calls `sda1` and so on.